# JNA Parameter Problems: Invalid memory Access

Tags: java, c++, memory, jna

I want to call the function "mytestFunction" in Java through JNA. This is how I call the Method in C++:

```
size_t input_length = 67U; 
uint8_t input[67U] = { 0x30, 0x41, 0x80, ....}; 
uint8_t *output_buffer = NULL; 
size_t output_length = 0; 
uint32_t errorCode = 0;
errorCode = mytestFunction(input, input_length, &output_buffer, &output_length);
```

This is how I call the Method in Java:

```
IcbdpClient cbdpFuncs = (IcbdpClient) Native.load("myDLL.dll", IcbdpClient.class); 
int[] input = new int[]{0x30, 0x41, 0x80, ....};
SizeT input_length = new SizeT(input.length);
Pointer output_buffer = new Memory(1);
SizeT output_length = new SizeT(0);
err = cbdpFuncs.mytestFunction(input, input_length, output_buffer, output_length);
```

I already called a Method with hust one byte[] Paramter. Everthing worked. But now when I do the cbdpFuncs.mytestFunction I get "java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access". I think I handle the paramters output_buffer and output_length false. But I dont know what is the right way.

EDIT:
in ICdpClient mytestFunction is called like:

```
 int mytestFunction (int[] input, SizeT input_length, Pointer output_buffer, SizeT output_length);
```

Comment: Definition of `mytestFunction` from `IcbdpClient` may help.

Comment: thx for your reply, see EdIT, IcbdpClient is just an interface

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: The Problem was I declared output_buffer and output_length false:This is the right form:

```
PointerByReference output_buffer = new PointerByReference();
IntByReference output_length = new IntByReference();
```

IF you want to use the Pointer after that, see here : https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/ByRefArguments.md